# React router updates the URL but the route is not being rendered (works after a manual refresh)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

These are my public routes

```js
export const PublicRoutes = () => {
    return (
        <Switch>
            <Route path="/" exact component={Login} />
            <Route path={constant.component.logout.url} exact={true}             component={Logout} />
            <Route path={constant.component.register.url} exact= {true} component={SignUp} />
            <Route path={constant.component.forgotPassword.url} exact={true} component={ForgotPassword} />
        </Switch>
    )
}
```

This is my index.js

```js
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <AlertProvider template={AlertTemplate} {...options}>
      <Router>
        <App />
      </Router>
    </AlertProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

This is my app.js where I am trying to render routes based on accessToken in the local storage

```js
  return (
    <>
      {token ? <DashboardLayout /> : <PublicRoutes />}
    </>
  )
```

And finally this my dashboard layout where I want the authenticated routes to be shown to the right of the sidebar

```js
        <>
                <SideBar>
                <div className="w-100">
                    <Switch>
                        <Route path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
                        <Route path="/my-account" component={Account} />
                    </Switch>
                </div>
                <Footer>
        </>
```

Now, when I login, it redirects me to "/dashboard" the url changes but the page shows an empty screen and it works if I refresh the page manually. What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure your token is not empty right after you login ? Maybe your token is empty at this moment, `PublicRoutes` is rendered and that's why the `/dashboard` route display an empty screen. Maybe your token only gets value after refresh.

Comment: I tried to log the token. It does not get logged till l refresh the page. I think the token is not getting updated. How do I ensure it does?

Comment: How do you manage you token ? Please share more code about it.

Comment: You were right, the token was not getting refreshed. What I did was I used context API + reducer to maintain an app state where I am storing the {token, isLoggedIn} and now I am rendering my routes based on isLoggedIn. It works. Thanks for your input.